# Symfony crawler can't access twig form

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

here is my code. I have a twig form

I want to access it using symfony WebTestCase crawler like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/testing.html#forms), but it doesn't work.
I want to use the Download button for testing purposes.

Does someone have a solution ?

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{ form(trackImageForm) }}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).prop('disabled', true);$('form[name={{ trackImageForm.vars.id }}]').submit()">Download</button>
</div>
```

i tried this

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Download')->form(array(...));
```

EDIT :

OK i can access to my form

```
{{ form_start(trackImageForm, {'attr': {'id': 'add_image_form'}}) }}
{{ form(trackImageForm) }}
```

i gave an id to my form and can n

```
$form = $crawler->filter('form#add_image_form')->form();
```

but will I be able to submit the form ?

Comment: About edit: Have you even read this docs that you've referred to? It's all there. `$client->submit($form);`

Comment: @JakubMatczak as you can read in the document; it's made to get a submit button from a form

Comment: @JakubMatczak if you check my code, the "Download button" is not in the form tags. Then it's completly different. That's why i asked it

Comment: See the update of my answer.

Comment: @JakubMatczak testing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation that you've referred to says:

> The selectButton() method can select button tags and submit input tags. **It uses several parts of the buttons to find them:**
>
> - The **value attribute value**;
> - The id or alt attribute value for images;
> - The **id or name attribute value** for button tags.

There's no button in your code matching these conditions.

You should give it a `name` or `id` attribute and use it in you test.

@About your edit:

If it's not a `<form>`, you cannot submit it. That's pretty obvious. Instead of making the submit with JavaScript, just put these buttons inside form as they should be. Using JS to submit the form in you case makes no sense.

If you don't want to put the submits in you form class (which is correct), you can do that with something like:

```
{{ form_start(trackImageForm) }} 
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{ form_rest(trackImageForm) }}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).prop('disabled', true);$('form[name={{ trackImageForm.vars.id }}]').submit()">Download</button>
    </div>
{{ form_end(trackImageForm) }}
```

- `form_start` prints `<form>` opening tag
- `form_rest` prints all fields that have not been printed yet (which is all in your case)
- `form_end` prints closing `</form>` tag